# Python: write at the specific position in a file

Tags: python, file-handling

I have two files one having let suppose list of keys while other file have keys and value pair written like below.

> keys```values

Now, assuming I have to search for each keys in the later file having key value pair and on matching the keys, have to write some value for specific key at the value's position.

Here is my code, which on running matches the pattern, shows the exact output at the console but on writing in the file writes at the end of the file instead.

````
import re
with open('perceive.txt','r') as jawabdo:
   for harsawal in jawabdo:

       with open('answers.txt','ab+') as letmethink:
           for spquestion in letmethink:
               sawal,jawab = spquestion.split("```")
               matching = re.match(sawal.lstrip('\r'),harsawal)
               if matching:
                   size = len(jawab)
                   if(size == 1):
                      jawab = "coming soon"
                      letmethink.write(jawab)
                      print('Answers written successfully!!!')
       letmethink.close()
jawabdo.close()
````

**Note:** perceive.txt is the file with keys while answers.txt is the file having key```value pair.

Comment: read answers fully first in a list/dict/whatever. Then write it in the end, the way you like.

Comment: it's like the file is going to grow and is a dynamic one which will keep updating with each new input, so the idea of storing in list/dict and then writing back to file don't seem feasible in this case. As the size of file has to increase and keep on increasing with each new key value pair.

Answer (score 2):

There's no possible way to write in a specific place in a text file

A good alternative is:

- Read the file `everything = letmethink.read()`
- Insert new data `everything = everything[:pos] + new_data + everything[pos + 1:]`
- Delete the file `letmethink.truncate()`
- Completely replace the file `letmethink.write(everything)`

If you don't want to do this then you have to use a database and sqlite3, with which you can insert data in specific locations

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a way to write to a certain position in the file. But it works kind of like inserting instead of appending between existing data.

As said in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=open#io.IOBase.seek):

> seek(offset, whence=SEEK_SET, /)
>
> Change the stream position to the given byte offset. offset is interpreted relative to the position indicated by whence. The default value for whence is SEEK_SET. Values for whence are:
>
> SEEK_SET or 0 – start of the stream (the default); offset should be zero or positive
>
> SEEK_CUR or 1 – current stream position; offset may be negative
>
> SEEK_END or 2 – end of the stream; offset is usually negative
>
> Return the new absolute position.

You can use `seek` function to perform your task (if, of course, it is suitable for you).

### Example

We have an `example.txt` with the following content: `StackOverflow`.

```
>>> file = open('example.txt', 'r+')
>>> file.seek(5)  # bytes
5
>>> file.write('123')
3
>>> file.read()
'rflow'
```

Now our new content is `Stack123rflow`. But you may notice that `read()` has shifted our cursor **after** the new data (`123`). To move it back you can use `file.seek(0)`.